# PHP Update page on POST

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have this little problem that when I POST something the page only updates after you refresh the page or change the page.

Example:

Money:
$1,000 -> (echo $money;)

```
if($_POST['add_money']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+ '1000' WHERE username = '".$name."'");
    echo "You added $1,000 to your money";
}
```

---

"Money" will still say $1,000 unless I change page or refresh.

I'm sure it something so small but I just cant seem to find out how to do it.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Your question is bit unclear, but the code should work regardless

Comment: after you update money, you have to get it again.  how are you updating the value?  What is the context of this?  Form?  AJAX request?

Comment: -0.25 for using `mysql_query` in 2012.  Look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: How would it benefit me?

Comment: Well, for one, you won't have to rewrite all your crap when they finally remove `mysql_query`.

Comment: For another, there's prepared statements.  You set up the query separately, and attach data to it rather than sticking it in the SQL string.  No more having to escape strings and stuff.

Comment: And of course, there's the fact that only w3schools dropouts use `mysql_query` anymore, since there are at least two far superior APIs out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out the other day.

What I had to do what change the variable on update so that it would change on the button click and not when changing the page.

```
if($_POST['add_money']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+ '1000' WHERE username = '".$name."'");
    echo "You added $1,000 to your money";
    $money = $money + 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['money'])){ 
    $_SESSION['money'] = 100;
}

if($_POST['add_money']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+ '1000' WHERE username = '".$name."'"); 
    $_SESSION['money'] = $_SESSION['money'] + 1000;
    echo "You added $1,000 to your money";
}

echo $_SESSION['money'];
```

Of course you can remove the session of money if you check the database first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work the way it is. Try this to confirm any errors

```
if($_POST['add_money']){
    $query = "UPDATE users SET money=money+ '1000' WHERE username = '".$name."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if($result) {
       echo "You added $1,000 to your money";
    }
}
```